# CLLocationManager returning multiple coordinates

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager

I am working on getting the location (lat\long) from the device at load, but it returns a varying number of coordinates each time (between 1 and 5 of each). I am just getting into Swift and I think I am missing something, but I have not been able to find anything on this other than needed to use .stopUpdatingLocation()

I think I might be missing something in Swift, but I am not sure what.

```
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if(CLLocationManager .locationServicesEnabled()){
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations:[AnyObject]! ) {
            var locationArray = locations as NSArray
            var locationObj = locationArray.lastObject as CLLocation
            var coord = locationObj.coordinate
            self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

            println(coord.latitude)
            println(coord.longitude)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the same thing with Objective-c and Android, and that is entirely usual. The numbers will become stabilized quickly on its own.

What I usually do is to calculate the change between two consecutive updates, once the change is pretty small - that means I got the correct coordinates by then.

By the way, once it is stabilized, I always reduce the frequency of location update to save energy.

Comment: PeiGuo -  So this is due to running in the viewDidLoad? When I run the same code from a touch or swipe, I just get one set of lat,long. It was just when moving to the viewDidLoad that it started doing this.

Comment: This only happens when you initially start to receive location updates, at which time you will first receive a swarm of incorrect data. Once stabilized, it is stabilized for good during the same run. Since ViewDidLoad is, I guess, before all the touches etc., it is not a surprise that this happened in ViewDidLoad. After all, it really has nothing to do with any particular method, but rather all about time sequence.